# Upgrade iPhone 5 from iOS 7 to iOS 8

Tags: upgrade, ios

I want to upgrade my iPhone 5 running iOS 7 to iOS 8. I dont want the current iOS 9 update in my device. Is there any way to update my phone to iOS 8 without iOS 9?

Comment: I guess you can. You need a laptop to download the iOS version you want and then install it on your device. You can find different versions of iOS on several websites.

Comment: No, it cannot be done. Your only options are 1. stay with what you're on, or 2. update to the latest iOS

Comment: iOS 9 is much better than iOS 8; way more secure, faster, and stable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this can be done you can download iOS firmware from http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

Once it is downloaded keep it on your desktop. Now put your device in DFU mode. (You can learn it from youtube if you dont know how to put your device in DFU mode.) iTunes will popup telling you it has discovered a device in recovery mode. Now press shift on your keyboard and click on restore. iTunes will start restoring your device.

NOTE: you might get few iTunes errors during the restore.

Comment: You cannot do this anymore, as Apple has stopped signing the firmware for iOS 8. Also, iOS 9 fixes a lot of bugs and has improvements to iOS 8.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yeah, iOS 9 is great.